# Which one is correct, specialization in or specializing in?

Tags: sentence-construction

Which one is correct, specialization in or specializing in?

This is to certify that ***A***, was a full-time postgraduate student in the Doctor of Philosophy majoring in
***X*** **specialization/specializing** in ***Y*** at *University Name*.

Do I need to include the word "**program**" before "**Doctor of Philosophy**"?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the correct sentence would be this:

> This is to certify that ***A***, was a full-time postgraduate student in the Doctor of Philosophy program. He/she was majoring in ***X***, and specializing in ***Y*** at ***University Name***.

Comment: can I write it like this (with commas):
This is to certify that A, was a full-time postgraduate student in the program of Doctor of Philosophy, majoring in X, specializing in Y at University Name.

Comment: You can make the whole thing one sentence with commas. However, it would be a long convoluted sentence. I'd recommend breaking it into separate clauses.

Also, that first comma in your sentence isn't necessary.

Comment: As @Reubend said, the first comma seems grammatically incorrect and changes the meaning of the sentence. The rest of the commas in his sentence seems fine.

Comment: @Reubend The first comma is also in your sentence.
Could you please check this: 
This is to certify that A was a full-time postgraduate student in the Doctor of Philosophy program. He/she majored in X, and specialized in Y at University Name.

Which one is better?